# sonar custom rule: disable 'system.out.println'

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

My goal is: raise issue when java file contain `System.out.println()`

rule code snipped:

```
public void visitNode(Tree tree) {
     //ohter code
     MethodMatcher matcher = MethodMatcher.create()
                .typeDefinition(TypeCriteria.anyType())
                .name("println")
                .withoutParameter();

    MethodInvocationTree methodInvocationTree = isTreeMethodInvocation(expressionTree.expression(), matcher);
    if(methodInvocationTree != null){
      reportIssue(tree, "msg");
    }
}
private static MethodInvocationTree isTreeMethodInvocation(ExpressionTree tree, MethodMatcher matcher) {
  Tree expression = ExpressionUtils.skipParentheses(tree);
  if (expression.is(Tree.Kind.METHOD_INVOCATION)) {
    MethodInvocationTree methodInvocation = (MethodInvocationTree) expression;
    if (matcher.matches(methodInvocation)) {
      return methodInvocation;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

test case code:

```
public class SaasDisableSystemOutPrintCheckCase {
   public void test() {
        test2222();
        System.out.println("aaa");
   }

   public void test2222() {} // Noncompliant
}
```

it not work?
but change code like this:

```
MethodMatcher matcher = MethodMatcher.create()
//.typeDefinition(TypeCriteria.is("java.io.PrintStream"))
                .name("test2222")
                .withoutParameter();
```

that's correct!

how to use `MethodMatcher` detect special expression?

thanks

Comment: Can I ask: why?

Comment: @DanBron   my goal or code not work？

Comment: Your goal: why prohibit `println`?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "it not work" ? and why is the standard rule from SonarJava https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarjava/rules.html#RSPEC-106 not covering your needs ?

Comment: @benzonico That's awesome. I didn't know that before